# How to type braces and dashes with mac keyboard

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, unity-dash, mac

I have an Apple US keyboard on my linux computer. All the keys work fine except the dash "-" and the open curly brace "{", which I have to copy and paste from elsewhere every time I need to type it. This proves especially annoying when using the terminal and when writing CSS. If anybody could help me out and tell me how to manually map these keys, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on creating a [custom keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions) although it seems a bit complicated IMO.
**Disclaimer:** The page mentions it is in need of an update so i'm not sure how applicable it is to 14.04

Instead try changing the current layout in System Settings > Text Entry and playing around with the Input sources. For most if not all US keyboards the **English (US)** layout should work correctly. I noticed there is an **English (Macintosh)** option you may want to try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The English (Macintosh) keyboard layout didn't change anything...
The article on creating custom keyboard layouts was interesting, however I found that the keys were already defined correctly. However I did find that I could use Unicode characters, which is certainly easier than copy and paste each time

Comment: As a latch ditch efffort, take a look at this bug on launchpad[link] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/214786). Some of the people there have mentioned an issue with some keys being swapped. Not sure if that is the case for you, but some people have reported issues with the curly brace as well. Someone in the post suggested a few fixes the simplest being `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout`.